# Trying to load to sftp server in r

Tags: r, curl, data-science, sftp

I really wanna upload a newly updated excel file which is stored on my local machine to the SFTP folder using r  script

here is the code using Curl and HTTP package

```
ftpUpload(what = "Glo_failed.xls",
to = "sftp://ubandaftp:*************://ubandaftp@159.152......../
C:/Users/Guesters/Desktop/AutoRecon/failed_report.xls")
```

But I'm getting this error below

```
Error in file(what, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(what, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'Glo_failed.xls': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error makes me think that the (relative) path to the file is incorrect. Check if the file is in the same folder as reported by `getwd()`.

Comment: The working directory is fine 
[1] "C:/Users/Guesters/Desktop/AutoRecon"

Comment: Sure. Is the file located in this folder, too? Can you list the content of the folder using `list.files(pattern = ".xls")` to double check?

Comment: Yes, it is present in the list.files

Comment: Don't you need to login to that server?